# How to remove a header/floating header from a WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress, header

(This question was resolved. The solution was to edit the header.php file)

The theme is True Mag.

The page has 2 headers now. The top (simplified one) is the one I made. The second one came with the theme. There is also a floating header as you get lower on the page. I want to remove the theme's own headers.

The single.php for the theme looks now like this:

```
<p style="background-color: #8D9FD9";> 
    <a href="http://www.webpage.org" style="font-size: 50px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none">&nbsp; Atyn</a> </p>

<?php if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
   COMMENTS... ...

global
        $st_Options,
        $st_Settings;

        $st_ = array();

        // Post format
        $st_['format'] = get_post_format( $post->ID ) ? get_post_format( $post->ID ) : 'standard';

        // Is title disabled?
        $st_['title_disabled'] = st_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'disable_title_value', true, 0 );

        // Is breadcrumbs disabled?
        $st_['breadcrumbs_disabled'] = st_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'disable_breadcrumbs_value', true, 0 );

        // Get custom sidebar
        $st_['sidebar'] = st_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sidebar_value', true, 'Default Sidebar' );

        // Get sidebar position
        $st_['sidebar_position'] = st_get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'sidebar_position_value', true, 'right' );

            // Re-define global $content_width if sidebar not exists
            if ( $st_['sidebar_position'] == 'none' ) {
                $content_width = $st_Options['global']['images']['large']['width']; }
            else {
                $content_width = $st_Options['global']['images']['post-image']['width']; }

/*===============================================

    P O S T
    Display a required post

===============================================*/



    get_header();

        ?>





            <div id="content-holder" class="sidebar-position-<?php echo $st_['sidebar_position']; ?>">

                <div id="content-box">

                    <div>

                        <?php
```

When I remove the "get header" it breaks the page. I don't see any other way on page to remove the header though (or replace it with my own).

Thanks.

Here is the header code (I insert it here because in comments it would wrap):

```
<?php if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; ?><!DOCTYPE html>
```

>

```
<head>
    <title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <div id="layout">

        <div id="header">

            <div id="header-layout">

                <div id="posts-featured">
                    <?php
                        // Posts featured
                        get_template_part( '/includes/posts/featured' );
                    ?>
                    <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
                </div>

                <div id="header-holder">

                    <div id="menu" class="div-as-table <?php global $st_Settings; if ( !empty( $st_Settings['stickymenu'] ) && $st_Settings['stickymenu'] == 'no' ) echo 'no-sticky-menu' ?>">
                        <div>
                            <div>

                                <div id="logo" class="div-as-table">
                                    <div>
                                        <div>
                                            <?php
                                                // Logo
                                                st_logo();
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- #logo -->

                                <span id="menu-select"></span>
                                <?php
                                    // Menu Primary
                                    st_menu_primary();
                                ?>

                                <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- #menu -->

                    <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>

                </div><!-- #header-holder -->

            </div><!-- #header-layout -->

            <div id="header-layout-2">

                <div id="header-holder-2">

                    <?php

                        // Icons the Social
                        if ( function_exists( 'st_icons_social' ) ) {
                            st_icons_social(); }

                        // Menu Secondary
                        st_menu_secondary();

                    ?>

                    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get" role="search" id="search-form-header">
                        <span></span>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="s"
                            value=""
                            placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search...', 'strictthemes' ) ?>"
                        />
                    </form>

                    <div class="clear"><!-- --></div>

                </div><!-- #header-holder-2 -->

                <?php
                    // Sidebar Ad A
                    if ( is_active_sidebar(4) ) {
                        get_template_part( '/includes/sidebars/sidebar_ad_a' ); }
                ?>

            </div><!-- #header-layout-2 -->

        </div><!-- #header -->

        <div id="content-parent">

            <div id="content-layout">
```

Comment: Can you post your header.php code

Comment: I wish I could do that. There is a header.php file, but it is empty (totally empty file). Think you might have a guess where I could find the content that should be in the header otherwise?

Comment: There's probably a hook somewhere that is populating the get_header. Maybe in your functions.php?

Comment: Wait, I found another copy of the folder with content in the header. I'm going to investigate that. If I can't find it still, I'll report back. Thanks for pointing me towards it.

Comment: It's not related, but there should be no output before `get_header();` (instead at the top you have some HTML)

Comment: I have included the header code in the original question. Yes, thanks, I didn't want to put that object up there before the get_header, but couldn't insert it otherwise to see what it looked like.

Comment: As @d79 said you should only have one `get_header();` and have nothing before it. If I inspect your page the meta tags that should be inside of head are now in your body.

Comment: I think the easiest solution would be to just modify and override the original theme's header html and css to fit your needs.

Comment: Yes, that seems best Paul Graffam

Answer (score 0):

Finally got rid of this! :)

```
#headline {
line-height: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
```

I also applied the following to my theme's css, in case you like them:

```
.pathway, .item-content-gradient {
visibility:hidden;}
.about-author, .video-toolbar-inner, .widget-top-rated, .widget-top-viewed, .widget-top-commented, .widget-top-liked, .widget-border {
border:hidden;}
```

Cheers!